# Delete current object entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am new to entity framework,I am working on a database first scenario.
I am working through a sample crud operation and I want to delete the current object thats in the Details view.

Currently I can only delete the first object in the view

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Branch delBranch = null;

    if (muTime.Branches.Count() > 0)
    {
        delBranch = muTime.Branches.First();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Records to delete");
        return;
    }

    muTime.Branches.Remove(delBranch);
    muTime.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("Deleted " + muTime.Branches.ToString());
    branchViewSource.View.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: A little bit more context please, is *muTime* a DbContext? Are you getting errors or simply after the operation there is no change at the database level?

Comment: What its doing is deleting the first record in the view and not the current record.muTime is the DbContext.I apologise I should have been more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring the record you want into tracking. Your current code is always going to delete the First() branch. You need to identify the control (grid?) or variable that points to the branch to delete.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    // get the id you want to delete from grid, other control or somewhere else
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
    var branchId = row.Cells["Id"].Value
    var branchToRemove = muTime.Branches.Find(branchId); // or whatever key is

    if (branchToRemove == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Records to delete");
        return;
    }

    muTime.Branches.Remove(branchToRemove);
    muTime.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("Deleted " + branchToRemove.ToString());  // or some property that identifies?
    branchViewSource.View.Refresh();
}
```